# A single word for terraced plaza?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Is there an English word for a plaza or forum in a park that is semicircular in shape, with rising decks on a slope similiar to how terraced farming is conducted?

Comment: Maybe an ***amphitheater***?

Comment: Nice one, Don.,,  actually Pizza, what the hell is the Italian word for that?? Is there such a specific word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the term you are looking for is [arena](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arena):

> - an enclosure or platform, usually surrounded by seats on all sides, in which sports events, contests, entertainments, etc, take place: a boxing arena.

(TFD)

[image: the]